# Modeling a POST API in a type safe way

Tags: haskell, typeclass, gadt

Haskell beginner here, trying to wrap a HTTP REST API in a safe way and with automatic Aeson decoding of return values. I started with a Haskell function for every API call. It was a bit boilerplateish, but ok.

Looking to improve things I wanted to turn each API call into a data type of its own. For example for logging in, I would model that as `Login` type that specifies the method, `Credentials` type for method parameters and `LoginReponse` for the result of the API call. Parameters and response types of course have corresponding FromJSON and ToJSON instances.

For two API calls it looks something like this (using GADTs):

```
data Void           = Void
data Credentials    = Credentials {...}
data LoginResponse  = LoginResponse {...}
data LogoutResponse = LogoutResponse {...}

data Command a where
    Login  :: Credentials -> Command LoginResponse
    Logout :: Void        -> Command LogoutResponse

execute :: FromJSON a => Command a -> IO a
execute cmd = do
    manager <- newManager tlsManagerSettings
    let request = buildHttpRequest cmd

    result <- httpLbs request manager
    let body = responseBody result
    let parsed = fromJust $ decode body

    return parsed
```

This works great for my use case - I can introspect Commands before executing them, I can't construct invalid API calls and Aeson knows how to decode the return values!

Only problem with this approach is that I have to keep all of my Commands in a single file under single data declaration.

I'd like to move method definitions (in my example `Login` and `Logout`) to separate modules, but to keep the `execute` function similar, and of course keep the type safety and Aeson decoding.

I've tried to make something using type classes, but got nowhere.

Any tips how to do that are welcome!

Comment: I think you might be interested in [servant](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant).

Comment: Firstly, using an existing library like servant is definitely the way to go here for practical purposes. If this is about learning, then you can address this issue by using [data families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Detailed_definition_of_data_families) - allowing you to essentially have an "open" datatype. Then you can have a class with the `buildHttpRequest` request function, the `Command` data family, and anything else you need. As a side note, the type you have named "Void" is usually just called `()` in Haskell (Void is usually reserved for the *empty* type).

Answer (score 2):

Since the only thing you do differently in `execute` for different commands is call `buildHttpRequest`, I propose the following alternate data type:

```
type Command a = Tagged a HttpRequest
```

(I don't know the return type of `buildHttpRequest`, so I made something up and assumed it returned an `HttpRequest`. Hopefully the idea will be clear enough even though I'm sure I got this part wrong.) The `Tagged` type comes from [tagged](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.3/docs/Data-Tagged.html#t:Tagged), and lets you attach a type to a value; it is the urphantom type. In our case, we will use the attached type to decide how to decode JSON in the `execute` step.

The type of `execute` needs a slight modification to demand that the attached type can be decoded:

```
execute :: FromJSON a => Command a -> IO a
```

However, its implementation remains basically unchanged; simply replace `buildHttpRequest` with `untag`. These commands are not conveniently introspectable, but you will be able to split things up along module boundaries; e.g.

```
module FancyApp.Login (Credentials(..), LoginResponse(..), login) where

import FancyApp.Types

data Credentials = Credentials
data LoginResponse = LoginResponse

login :: Credentials -> Command LoginResponse
login = {- the old implementation of buildHttpRequest for Login -}

module FancyApp.Logout (LogoutResponse(..), logout) where

import FancyApp.Types

data LogoutResponse = LogoutResponse

logout :: Command LogoutResponse
logout = {- the old implementation of buildHttpRequest for Logout -}
```